# Display route component in new tab and hide origin page component [Angular 2]

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular, angular2-routing

I'm displaying a component containing routerLink links in its HTML template. I would like to open the components corresponding to those routerLink links in a new tab when the user clicks on them, and to **only**  display those components (I don't want to display the component containing the routerLink links in the new tab).

Here is what I tried so far:

Here is the component containing the component which has routerLink links in its HTML Template (Let's call it container.component.html):

```ts
<div>
    <h1>{{title}}</h1>
    <comp></comp>
</div>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Here is the template of the `comp` component:

```ts
<div>
    <div>{{compName}}</div>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a [routerLink]="['/comp-info/comp-info-child/:compName', {compName: compName}]" target="_blank">info child</a>     
        </li>
        <li>
            <a [routerLink]="['/comp-info/comp-history']" target="_blank">comp history</a>      
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Here is my app.routes.ts file, defining the routes of the application:

```ts
/*
  Necessary imports here
*/

export const routes: RouterConfig = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: EmptyComponent,
  },
  {
    path: 'comp-info',
    component: CompInfoComponent,
    children: [
      { path: 'comp-info-child/:compName',  component: CompInfoChildComponent },
      { path: 'comp-history',     component: CompHistoryComponent }
    ]
  }
];


export const APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS = [
  provideRouter(routes)
];
```

and here is the comp-info.component.html file:

```ts
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

I manage to navigate through the components using the routerLinks but the `comp` component is still displayed, it seems like I'm displaying the container.component.html view instead of the comp-info.component.html view.

Comment: I would like to ask you to solve? If the solution can also tell me?